# jQuery select based on text

Tags: jquery

I need to select an element based on its text in jQuery.

For instance:

```
<span>this text</span>
```

I know I can use .contains() to select based on text, but it's not exclusive.

I don't want to select:

```
<span>this text and that text</span>
```

I want to select the element if it's the only text of the element.

Aside from using regex, how do I do this with jQuery selectors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have some leverage with the :contains selector, but that only goes so far.  You will need to further trim down the set of elements based on exact text matches, as in:

```
$("span:contains(this text)")
.filter
(
  function()
  {
    return $(this).text() === "this text";
  }
)
```

This makes the initial contains usage technically unnecessary, but you may experience performance benefits by starting out with a smaller collection of SPAN elements before filtering down to the exact set you're interested in.

**EDIT**: Took Ken Browning's suggestion to use the `text()` function instead of `innerHTML` for string comparison within the `filter` function.  The idea being that `innerHTML` will capture text that we're not particularly interested in (including markup).

Comment: Good answer, but why use `innerHTML` instead of `$(this).text()`?  Wouldn't using `innerHTML` require him to account for cases where the criteria includes characters which have to be encoded (like & -> &amp;)

Comment: For nitpicking, I gave you +1 and a referral in the answer!

Comment: @DavidAndres Instead of `innerHTML` you could also use `innerText` which is faster than `.text()` and would not include markup.