# Table cell conditional formatting based on content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, formatting, conditional-statements

I simply have a table with a bunch of ✔ X and a few other symbols, how can I change the class of a cell based on it's contents?

**jQuery example:**

```
$(function(){$("td:has('✔')").addClass("tick"); });
$(function(){$("td:has('X')").addClass("cross"); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also covered in post [jQuery select based on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text/1430308#1430308).

You can widdle down the set of TD elements to only those td elements whose text exactly matches your expectations.

```
$("td")
  .filter
  (
    function()
    {
      return $(this).text() === "✔";
    }
  )
  .addClass("tick");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine if the cell contains the symbol...

```
$("td:contains('✔')").addClass("tick");
```

...but if we are looking for something like hyphen (-) how ca nwe determine this is the only content of the cell instead of just containing it?

Any better solutions?