# Select element based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select an element based on their innertext in JQuery. Below is my Html

```
<html>
    <body> 
        <a href="fddf">4</a> 
        <a href="fddf">4</a> 
        <a href="fddf">4</a> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

I want to select all the `<a>` tags which has text of "4". Any idea how do I do it?

Comment: You can add HTML or source code to your question by indenting it with four spaces.  (or by clicking the Format Code (`1010`) button in the toolbar)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text

Answer (score 16):

You're looking for the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), like this:

```
$('a:contains("4")')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct way is `$("a[outerText='4']")`. Contains returns `4,44,444` etc. .

Comment: No, that selects all `a` elements with an **attribute** `outerText` valued `4`: eg.: `<a outerText="4">`. Since there is no HTML attribute called `outerText` that is probably not what you want. There is a DOM property with the same name *in IE* (and WebKit and Opera which copied the extension), and jQuery's selector engine will incorrectly use it when available because IE gets confused about the difference between an attribute and a property.

Comment: Even when the `outerText` property is available, the above code will fail on all modern browsers, because the `$()` will get optimised out to a call to the browser's native `querySelectorAll()` method. This method interprets the selector correctly and thus will not allow you to use `outerText` in an attribute selector to refer to the property of the same name. So this hack will only work on IE6-7.