# CSS3: Show/Hide based on node contents

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS 3 content selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/css-3-content-selector)

I couldn't find a way online to hide or show elements based on their contents in CSS. More specifically, in the following example, I'm searching for a CSS3 rule that would allow me to hide all `<tr>` entries whose second `<td>` child contains `File`.

```
<tr>
    <td>Succeded</td>
    <td>File</td>
    <td>Create</td>
    <td>Left->Right</td>
    <td>\Thunderbird\00sqrcu5.default.archive.7z</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Succeded</td>
    <td>Folder</td>
    <td>Create</td>
    <td>Left->Right</td>
    <td>\Thunderbird\mab</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Failed</td>
    <td>File</td>
    <td>Create</td>
    <td>Left->Right</td>
    <td>\Thunderbird\mab\abook.mab</td>
</tr>
```

Is this even possible? I know that it would be better to add attributes to the `<tr>` elements, but I'm not sure if an attributes-based solution would support complex rules such as "second child is not 'Folder' and first is 'Failed'".

Ideas?

Comment: Not with CSS selectors. XPath, I'm not sure.

Comment: I know this could easily be done with jQuery. Not with CSS.

Comment: Attribute-based solution? What do you mean exactly by that? Can you add the text of the node as an attribute (for example, `<td t="File">`)?

Comment: jQuery solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all of those elements with XPath:

```
var headings = document.evaluate(
  "//tr[td[2][contains(text(),'File')]]",
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
  null
);
while(a = headings.iterateNext()) { console.log(a); }
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/7MdyU/)

Not with css: Can't backtrack.

**Edit:**

See Dan's post (below) for an explanation of the pieces. The difference between the two is that I start with the `tr` element and give it a condition that it must contain a `td` with `"File"`, whereas Dan's solution starts with the `td` element, specifies that it must contain `"File"`, then backs up a level to the `tr`.

Also, he includes a link to a [great XPath test page](http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/).

Comment: I was curious about the performance so I created this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/xpath-element-with-second-child-containing-text) test. It seems that your xpath is faster, great job :)

Comment: @Dan: Well, then I got lucky! (I've rarely used XPath besides in some xslt ages ago.) Also, your testing link is cool.

Comment: I almost never use xpath. I prefer jQuery and the like. I already +1'ed you :)

Comment: AAaah, not sure which answer to accept now :) Both great, upvoted both =)

Answer (score 4):

- CSS3 : **no**
- javascript: **yes**
- xpath: **yes** (something like `//td[2][contains(text(),'File')]/..`)

The xpath works like this:

- `//td` = select tds anywhere in the document
- `[2]` = restrict them to those that are the second child
- `[contains(text(),'File')]` = restrict them to those that have File in their text
- `..` = go up one level (to the `tr`)

You can quickly [test your xpath here](http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/)

Comment: +1: Better explanation of the XPath, plus a better testing link.

Answer (score -1):

Try This. You stated

> I'm searching for a CSS3 rule that would allow me to hide all  entries whose second  child contains File.

So I assume it is always the second child

```
td:nth-child(2)
{
display: none;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XanUS/)

Comment: @JAA149 in one case the second child does not have File as content.

Comment: You can't make that kind of assumption.

Comment: Change your markup. Add the title attribute with a value of "file" to every td that has the content as file and use attribute selector such as td[title="file"]{display: none;}

Comment: Or you can try this
tr:first-child > td:nth-child(2)
{
    display: none;
}

tr:last-child > td:nth-child(2)
{
    display: none;
}

http://jsfiddle.net/XanUS/1/

Comment: @JAA149: I think you are missing the point, he wants to hide the entire tr (but only if its second child has 'File' in it).

Comment: I think, he wants to hide the td which has the content of file and not the tr. In any case, solutions other than CSS are best here as posted by others. If an only CSS solution required, I can think of only the above.