# jQuery selection based on span content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery select based on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text)

I have something like this:

```
<span>abc</span>
<span>a</span>
```

I need to select only the second span but with `$("span:contains("a"))` jQuery select both the spans. How can I select only the span with the exact text matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code. `html()` is used instead of `.text()`, to only match a span which doesn't contain other elements.

> `<span><span>a</span></span> <--` The `text` method would select both span elements.

```
$("span").filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() == "a";
})
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir According to http://api.jquery.com/filter/, this feature is available at 1.0+

Comment: i think it's what i need. it should work correctly, i just have some problems adapting it to my case but for now, ty.