# Partial match on JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

To get all `<td>` elements text that starts with "ELEC...", I am doing -

```
$('td.id').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('ELEC') == 0) {}
});
```

Is there a simpler way to do this, something like `$('td.id:contains("ELEC*")')` ?

Comment: The code you have written isn't looking for elements whose text starts with "ELEC"; it is looking for elements whose text contains "ELEC". Which did you want?

Comment: Potential duplicate, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text)

Answer (score 5):

To get only elements that start with ELEC, use the `.filter` method.

```
$("td.id").filter(function(){
    return /^ELEC/.test($(this).text());
});
```

or the slightly more efficient

```
var $collection = $("td.id");
$collection.filter(function(i){
    return /^ELEC/.test($collection.eq(i).text());
});
```

Comment: Why is this better than the `.indexOf("Elec") == 0` that the OP was using?  In all cases .indexOf is faster than using a regex.

Comment: It is better because this one actually creates a collection of elements that you can use rather than running code on each element individually. For example, with my sample you could do `$collection.addClass("foobar")`. Using his original code, he would be doing `$(this).addClass('foobar')` inside the if statement.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that's exactly how you do it (I removed the wildcard asterisk, as its not needed.):

```
$('td.id:contains("ELEC")')
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Ahh, I missed the "starts with" contraint on the question.

Comment: The question is ambiguous -- it asks about "starts with" and then shows example code that implements "contains".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if we combine the best of several different proposals, we'd get something faster since a regex is not really called for here:

```
$("td.id").filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text().substr(0, 4) == "Elec");
}).whateverMethodYouWant();
```

Or a bit faster, that uses less jQuery:

```
$("td.id").filter(function() {
    return ((this.textContent || this.innerText).substr(0, 4) == "Elec");
}).whateverMethodYouWant();
```