# jQuery: how do I select paragraphs based on their content

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery select based on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text)

I am learning drupal. I want to add some jquery to a site. I know I can and probably will later, go back and add id's and classes so I can access things easier, but I want to know how to use 'has' or 'contents' and or 'filter' correctly.

On my page I have a ton of paragraphs, I want to select the `<p>`'s based on their contents and then do something with them, so for example I want:

```
jQuery('p').has('What is Supplemental').css('background-color', 'red')
```

How would I do that?

Site example here: http://surety.lfwebz.com

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about :contains?

```
$('p:contains("What is Supplemental")').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf("What is Supplemental") > -1;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$('p').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == 'What is Suppemental';
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

As `:contains` could cause issues because it doesn't check for an exact match, for example, `p:contains("What is Supplemental")...` would also match "What is Supplemental [FILL IN THE BLANK]" or "[FILL IN THE BLANK] What is Supplemental".

EDIT:

That could also be true of using `indexOf`, though it would only apply to text appended to the match.

Comment: Maybe he wants to match those, too. The question isn't very specific.

Comment: Very true - just looking for 'needle in haystack' scenarios, `:contains` is a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or `each`:

```
jQuery('p').each(function(i){
 str = jQuery(this).html();
 if(str.indexOf('What is Supplemental') !== -1){
   jQuery(this).css('background-color', 'red');
 }
});
```