# .find Inquiry about how to find <a> text

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get

How would I find certain text on a page under an  tag?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var Link = "http://www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=34039"

function her() {
    $.get(Link, function (data) {
        if ($(data).find('No One!').length) {
            Post()
            LoL()
        }
    })
}
her()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select based on text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text)

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieving data as HTML then you can do line below

```
// below example statement will Find all anchors that has No One! Text

var phraseToFind = "No One!";
//links that contain above phrase example.
var isAnyLinkWithPhraseFound = $(data).find('a:contains('+ phraseToFind +')').length > 0;
```

Your function will get change like below:

```
function her() {
   var phrase = "No One!";
   $.get(Link, function (data) {
        if ($(data).find('a:contains('+ phrase +')')
                   .filter(function(){return $(this).text() === phrase }).length) {
        //this filter will give links with exact phrase
            Post()
            LoL()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I want the exact phrase 'No One!' to be found on the page, its HTML.