# Select element based on the content within

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have html like this:

```
<a href='#'>Apple</a>
<a href='#'>Orange</a>
<a href='#'>Apple</a>
```

How would I select only the links that say have the content of `Apple` within?

Comment: What do you mean with select?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select based on text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430290/jquery-select-based-on-text)

Comment: Well, horrible performance, but you could do: jQuery( ":contains(text)" )

Comment: @PeterKA - Related, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**:contains()**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
$("a:contains('Apple')").addClass("apple");
```

```css
.apple {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>Apple</a>
<a href='#'>Orange</a>
<a href='#'>Apple</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jquery's filter method http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
var Apples = $('a').filter(function () {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Apple';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the content with the :contains jquery selector:

HTML:

```
<a href='#'>Apple</a>
<a href='#'>Orange</a>
<a href='#'>Apple</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('a:contains("Apple")').css("color","red");
```

Don't forget to include the Jquery library if you didn't include it before:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/p1x3n43s/